# Remove An HTML Image Link String Within A String Using PHP

Tags: php

I have a table field and the data could have within it a string for an image file like this:

```
<div class="postedImage"><img src="assets/images/posts/5c393d238bc3a2kcknk.jpg"></div>
```

The string will always be the same except for the image filename.

Using PHP I need to find and remove the whole string from the beginning `<div` tag through the ending `</div>` tag.

In VB.Net I would use instr to find the location of `<div class="postedImage">` and then use instr to find the location of `</div>` using the first find's position to start.  With that I would then do a Replace to an empty string.

I'm new to PHP and though I know about strpos and str_replace, I can't quite get it to do the exact same thing I can in VB.Net.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know VB but maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php with `strpos` is close to that `insrt`. `str_replace` is for a string, not a position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but that didn't work.

I found the `strip_tags` function, and that did exactly what I wanted.  It removes HTML tags

```
$body = strip_tags($body);
```

Comment: If this is what worked for you, you should accept your own answer.